# What's the "built-in" firewall in OS X 10.9?

Tags: macos, firewall

By "built-in" I mean the backend of the System firewall (System Preference->Security&Privacy->Firewall). Is it ipfw or pf? (I know that ipfw was the backend for previous versions of OS X).

And, what are the commands/logs that I can use to determine which firewall is running?

Comment: Excellent article on the topic: http://blog.scottlowe.org/2013/05/15/using-pf-on-os-x-mountain-lion/

Answer (score 4):

The firewall in OS X 10.9 is now "pf".

It is controlled by the tool `pfctl` which can also give you a lot of status about the firewall itself. Try `sudo pfctl -s all` and you will get a huge dump of info. If you want a lot of information you can add one or two `-v` to the front of the options for even more info - `sudo pfctl -v -v -s all`